# Understanding adding from list in J

Tags: j

I'm working through a book on J and have the answers to the exercises, but am having trouble understanding why they work.

Here is the question:

> Peter and Paul’s golf scores are given turn about in the form of a
>   list "y.", for example 3 4 4 4 5 6 3 3 7 2 etc. Write an expression
>   which gives the difference between the total of Peter’s scores and the
>   total of Paul’s scores. Write a further expression which obtains the
>   total scores for both Peter and Paul over 18 holes.

The answer to the first question is:

```
-/y
```

I understand that this is inserting n-1 subtraction symbols between each item in the list, effectively getting the difference of their scores on each hole, and giving you the sum at the end.

The answer to the second question is:

```
(36$0 1)+//.y
```

I don't understand how to think through this answer.  From right to left,

1. You're taking list "y"
2. inserting n-1 copies of a verb into that list
3. Then "+/" tells you that you're going to do that in a specific way...
4. The parenthetical dyadic tells you...??? this is where I get lost.

Clearly, it's telling the interpreter to sum the atoms alternately, yielding two sums.  But I don't get how / why.

I'd appreciate any enlightenment you guys can provide.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using **key `/.`:**

Key `x v/. y` applies a verb `v` on all elements of `y` but **grouped by** x:

```
0 0 1 0 1 2 < /. 1 2 3 4 5 6
┌─────┬───┬─┐
│1 2 4│3 5│6│
└─────┴───┴─┘

0 0 1 0 1 2 +/ /. 1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 6
```

In your case, the grouping is `(36 $ 0 1)` and the verb to be applied is `+/` (let's say `y =: i.36`):

```
36 $ 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
(36 $ 0 1) < /. y
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34│1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21  23 25 27 29 31 33 35│
└────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(36 $ 0 1) +//. y
306 324
```

For this particular problem, what I would prefer to do is shape `$` `y` appropriately and just sum the corresponding axis. For example:

```
18 2 $ y     NB. or even better _2 ,\y
0  1
2  3
4  5
...
+/ 18 2 $ y
306 324
```